# How to show column header to a row in a excel sheet and pass those to mysql without VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, phpmyadmin

I have following table in a excel sheet.

[image]

So what I want to do is to get headers into column if there is asterisk symbol inside a cell.
like below

```
+---+-----------+
|ID | categories|
+---+-----------+
| 1 | LH1,LH2   |
| 2 | LH1,LH3   |
| 3 | LH2       |
| 4 | LH3       |
+---+-----------+
```

and pass these table into phpmyadmin. Is there any way to do this without using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You can make queries from your Excel file. With these queries you can make a SQL script file, which you can run with PHPAdmin to insert the data in the table concerned.
Here is the formula (French version, please replace ";" by "," and "SI" by "IF" and "OU" by "OR" :

```
="INSERT INTO myTable(ID, categories) VALUES(" & SI(OU(B3="*";C3="*";D3="*");A3&",";"") &SI(B3="*";"'"&B$1&SI(C3="*";","&C$1&SI(D3="*";","&D$1;"");SI(C3="*";","&C$1;SI(D3="*";","&D$1;"")));SI(C3="*";"'"&C$1;SI(D3="*";"'"&D$1;""))) & "');"
```

it must be copied in the one cell (G2 for example). Then apply this formula on the lines concerned.
With this formula, I get the following query lines:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(ID, categories) VALUES(1,'LH1,LH2');
INSERT INTO myTable(ID, categories) VALUES(2,'LH1,LH3');
INSERT INTO myTable(ID, categories) VALUES(3,'LH2');
INSERT INTO myTable(ID, categories) VALUES(4,'LH3');
```

hope this can help